# What does negative address mean in assembly?

Tags: assembly

```
0xffffffff8100b9e4: callq  *-0x7ec55ec0(,%rax,8)
```

What does `*-0x7ec55ec0` mean here?

Answer (score 3):

In this context, `-0x7ec55ec0` is just a shorter way to write `0xffffffff813aa140` (in other words, `-0x7ec55ec0 + 0x10000000000000000`).

Presumably, there's a jump table at that address, indexed by `rax`.

If it's any help, the same instruction in Intel assembly syntax is:

```
call qword ptr [0xffffffff813aa140 + rax*8]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no negative addresses. Addresses are unsigned.

What it means is that you took an address with the high bit set, and formatted it as a signed number (or used a method that formatted it as a signed number).

Comment: whether addresses are signed or unsigned is pretty much up to interpretation and/or personal preference. One way to look at it is that, e.g. in x64/x86_64, if you accept addresses as 47bit-signed then the address space is contiguous, `[-2^48 .. 2^48-1]`. If you insist on treating them unsigned, you end up with this "canonical"/"noncanonical" thing of _two_ separate valid address ranges, `[0 .. 2^48-1]` and `[2^64-2^48 .. 2^64-1]` (and anything in between being "noncanonical", not representable).

Comment: If, by "interpretation", you mean how the number is formatted as a string, then that's exactly what I said. However, I fail to see what this has to do with "personal preference." Where have you ever seen computer addresses described in terms of being negative?

Comment: It's a simple consequence of how "canonical" addressing (address spaces with holes in them) works - what's easier to accept, that the total addressing range is contiguous (and can be negative), or that there's just a range of "values" that aren't addresses ? Also, you have no problem accepting that address _offsets_ can be negative, then what stops _addresses_ from becoming negative ?

Answer (score 0):

"0x7ec55ec0" is a negative address *offset*. And yes, it will be subtracted from the value of 8*%rax. This subtraction is in the two complements representation of a 64 bit unsigned equivalent to adding "0xffffffff8100b9e4".

Presumably the value of %rax*8 will by greater than 0x7ec55ec0, so that a value in the usual range of the code or data segment results.

Note that address offsets on a x86 platform are indeed always signed (both 8 bit and 32 bit offests), but the resulting addresses are of course unsigned.