# Very large address copied as negative value

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, mov

I was going through a binary file corresponding to a C program.
I have a very large address stored in `%eax`.
When tried to see the value via `gdb`, it prints a negative value (reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5427963/4954434)).

Now when `mov %eax, 0x4c(%esp)` is performed, the resulted value in `0x4c(%esp)` is sometimes positive and sometimes negative. This effect `cmp $0, 0x4c(%esp)` statement that follows!

Can someone please explain this behavior?

If this helps:
`core: ELF 32-bit LSB core file Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style`

Comment: How are you actually displaying those values in `gdb`?

Comment: The sequence of bit you are copying is always the same, the interpretation may be different though, probably gdb is defaulting to a two's complement 32bit value

Comment: I'm displaying `%eax` using `print %eax`

Comment: How are you displaying the contents of `0x4c(%esp)`?

Comment: Anyway, if you are using `print $esp+0x4c` you are not displaying the contents that are at the address `$esp+0x4c`, but the address itself.

Comment: FWIW, it does not affect the `cmp` instruction. It merely sets different flags, and it is up to you to interpret them, e.g. in conditional jumps using `ja`, `jb` (for unsigned comparison) or `jg`, `jl` (for signed comparison), or using `seta`, `setb`, etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registers do not have signs; they hold bits. It's up to you how you interpret them. The same holds for the stack: it holds bits, and it's up to you how to interpret them. If you move a value from a register to the stack, the bits are copied. And if you interpret bits on the stack like you interpret bits in a register, you get the same value.

Note that there *are* instructions which interpret those bits as values - multiply, compare, etcetera. But `MOV` isn't one of those.

Comment: plus1  for explaining the difference between data and interpretation of such data

Comment: But, when `0x4c(%esp)` is used for `cmp`, I get different results. Why is it so?

Comment: @JithinPavithran: I've got no idea what it means. Guessing: did you mean that immediately after, `cmp %eax, 0x4c(%esp; jne ...` jumps? I've got no idea why that sequence would occur in compiled C code.

Comment: No not right after. After mov, there is a `jmp` (condition-less), then comes the `cmp` and then `jmp` depending on the result. (The code has a heisenbug, I'm trying to understand it in depth)

Comment: @JithinPavithran: the stored value in memory by the `mov %eax,(...)` is 32 bit value. You can interpret it any way you wish, it's still the same value (at bit level). Whatever is puzzling you about the *"`cmp` and code flow"* must have some other reason, the `cmp $0,...` against address is sort of ridiculous, as usually the only good reason to test address against zero is to catch `nullptr` value, so the value of sign bit doesn't matter then either (one of `jz(je)/jnz(jne)` is then used). Hard to say what you see there, as you didn't post it in question.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of bit you are copying is always the same, the interpretation may be different though, probably gdb is defaulting to a two's complement 32bit value

how to change gdb output format:

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Output-Formats.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following command in GDB:

```
print $esp-0x4c
```

You are actually displaying the *address* `-0x4c(%esp)` (i.e.: the value of the register `esp` plus the offset `-0x4c`) and **not** the *content located at this address*. In order to display the *contents* of `-0x4c(%esp)` (i.e.: to see what's actually *at this address*) you can use the `x` command:

```
x $esp-0x4c
```